# Vertically centering label for three subfigures

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, subfloats, labels

Vertically centering label for three subfigures
I want to put one label on the left corresponding to 3 images; it's on the bottom left and I'd like it to be vertically centered.

This is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[th]

{(a)} \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm] {capture1}
                \label{}

\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm] {capture2}
                \label{}

\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm] {capture3}
                \label{}

}
\caption{$(a-c)$ Phase portraits corresponding to attractors for $\protect%
\beta=-1.275$.}
\label{fig7}
\end{figure}
```

Here's what this compiles to. 
[image]

I would like it to look like this.
[image]

Comment: Note that the `subfigure` package has been obsolete for 15 years and that `subfig` or the more modern `subcaption` packages should be used.

Answer (score 2):

Some manual work, but this seems to be what you're looking for. Note that `subfigure` has been obsolete for several years and `subfig` is much better, if not `subcaption` that, however, has quite a different syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\captionsetup[subfigure]{farskip=0pt}

\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}ccc@{}}
\raisebox{.8cm}{\subfloat[\label{testA}]{\qquad}} &
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{example-image} \\
\raisebox{.8cm}{\subfloat[\label{testB}]{\qquad}} &
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{example-image} \\
\raisebox{.8cm}{\subfloat[\label{testC}]{\qquad}} &
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{example-image} \\
\end{tabular}

\caption{(a-c) Phase portraits corresponding to attractors for $\beta=-1.275$.}
\label{fig7}

\end{figure}

References to \ref{testA}, \ref{testB} and \ref{testC}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `\centerbox` command which you wrap around all the images you want to include. Technically, it's not the label "(a)" which is off, but the images only get placed with zero offset. That's what you can change with a `\raisebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\newcommand{\centerbox}[1]{\raisebox{1ex}{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[th]
{(a)}
\subfigure{
\centerbox{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{Black}}
\centerbox{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{Black}}
\centerbox{\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=4cm]{Black}}
}
\label{fig7}
\caption{$(a-c)$ Phase portraits corresponding to attractors for $\protect%
\beta=-1.275$.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it does not work  , I'm unable todisplay  image

Comment: sorry, yes, you need `graphicx` at the beginning. I updated the example, it assumes a file called `Black`to exist.